# How to pass value from html form without using submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

Current code:
index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">            
            $('#username').blur(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: {text:$(this).val()}
                });
            });
        </script>    

        <form id="search" action="search.php"  method="post">
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="30" placeholder="username ..." />
              <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="sa" value="search" />
        </form>
```

search.php

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['username'];
?>
```

If I press the submit button it works well but I want to send the value from the field once I focuse out of the field, without pressing the submit button.

Comment: I think you have typo here `$('#usernamecopy')`

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, I fixed that but the problem is not that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

```
 $('#usernamecopy').focusout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: {username :$('#username').val()}
                });
            });
```

In php file you can use:

```
$user= $_REQUEST['username'];
```

Comment: I still getting nothing when refresh the search php page...
Notice: Undefined index: username in ..... on line 5

Comment: try to add data text : $('#username').val()

Comment: Shouldn't the data portion read `{username:...}` and not `{text:...}`?

Comment: Of course :) You can try now i modified my example.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I think if you change `data: {text:$(this).val()}` to `data: {text:$("#usernamecopy").val()}`; it will work because when you put `this` inside the `data`; the `this` refers to the `data` instead of `#usernamecopy` . By the way, I hope you are not mistaking `#usernamecopy` with `#username`

Comment: I still getting nothing when refresh the search.php page... Notice: Undefined index: username in ..... on line 5.
Yes, sorry about that #usernamecopy is a mistake, because I have another field for my test.

Comment: does it work? `data: JSON.stringify({text:$('#username').val()})`

Comment: nope, same result.. might be because echo $_POST['username']; is not right?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use following code in JavaScript :**

     <script type="text/javascript"> 

            $('#username').blur(function(){
                var value = $("#username").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: "username="+value,
                    success: function(data){

                    }
                });                    
            });

     </script>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in ..... on line 5. Do you thing something is wrong with the .php page?